# How do I setup Signals and Slots in PyQt with QThreads in both directions?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread, qt-signals

This is a followup-question based on ekhumoro's answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52005755/4464653) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818401/4464653).

---

I thought to understand, that when a slot is correctly defined with `pyqtSlot` and assigned to `QThread` (e.g. with `moveToThread()`), it will be executed in this QThread and not the calling one. Furthermore, making the connection with `Qt.QueuedConnection` or `Qt.AutoConnection` is also required.

I wrote Code to test this. My goal is to achive something quite simple like this:
[image]
Gui with a button, that starts some time-consuming-work and return with a result to display back in the GUI.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    change_text = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton('Push me!', self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

        print('main running in:', QThread.currentThread())
        thread = Thread(change_text, self)
        thread.start()
        self.button.clicked.connect( thread.do_something_slow, Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.change_text.connect(self.display_changes, Qt.QueuedConnection)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def display_changes( self, text ):
        self.button.setText(text)

class Thread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, signal_to_emit, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.signal_to_emit = signal_to_emit
        #self.moveToThread(self) #doesn't help

    @pyqtSlot()
    def do_something_slow( self ):
        print('Slot doing stuff in:', QThread.currentThread())
        import time
        time.sleep(5)
        self.signal_to_emit.emit('I did something')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    app.exec()
```

But .. the gui is blocking and the slot is called in the main-thread.
What am I missing? Have to be something small (I hope).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you are confusing that `QThread` is a *Qt thread*, that is, a new thread created by Qt, but no, `QThread` is a class that **handles** native threads, only the `run()` method is running on another thread, other methods live in the thread where the `QThread` lives, which is a `QObject`,

**In what thread does a QObject live?**

The thread in which a `QObject` lives is that of the parent, if it does not have a parent it will be the thread where it was created. On the other hand, a `QObject` can move to another thread using `moveToThread()`, and all of its children will also move. Only `moveToThread()` can be used if the `QObject` has no parent, otherwise it will fail.

---

A methodology to use `QThread` is to create a class that inherits from `QThread` and override the run method and call `start()` so that it starts running `run()`, in the `run()` method the heavy task would be done, but in your case not This form can be used because the task will not be executed continuously. A better option than the heavy task is part of a `QObject`, and that `QObject` move it to another thread.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    change_text = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton('Push me!', self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)
        print('main running in:', QThread.currentThread())
        # A Worker without a parent is created 
        # so that it can be moved to another thread.
        self.worker = Worker(self.change_text)
        thread = QThread(self) 
        self.worker.moveToThread(thread)
        thread.start()
        # All methods of self.worker are now executed in another thread.
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.worker.do_something_slow)
        self.change_text.connect(self.display_changes)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def display_changes( self, text ):
        self.button.setText(text)


class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self, signal_to_emit, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.signal_to_emit = signal_to_emit

    @pyqtSlot()
    def do_something_slow( self ):
        print('Slot doing stuff in:', QThread.currentThread())
        import time
        time.sleep(5)
        self.signal_to_emit.emit('I did something')
```

On the other hand it is not necessary to indicate the type of connection since by default it is `Qt::AutoConnection`, this type of connection decides in runtime if you use `Qt::DirectConnection` if the receiver lives in the same wire from where the signal was emitted, otherwise, `Qt::QueuedConnection` is used. As you realize, the Worker does not have a parent, so for it to have a life cycle equal to the class it must be an attribute of it since otherwise it would be a local variable that is eliminated. On the other hand, note that `QThread` receives a parent than a MainWindow, so `QThread` will live in the GUI thread but it handles a secondary thread.

---

With the Worker concept it is better that the change_text signal no longer belongs to the GUI but to the worker decoupling the objects better.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton('Push me!', self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

        print('main running in:', QThread.currentThread())
        self.worker = Worker()
        thread = QThread(self)
        self.worker.moveToThread(thread)
        thread.start()
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.worker.do_something_slow)
        self.worker.change_text.connect(self.display_changes)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def display_changes( self, text ):
        self.button.setText(text)

class Worker(QObject):
    change_text = pyqtSignal(str)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def do_something_slow( self ):
        print('Slot doing stuff in:', QThread.currentThread())
        import time
        time.sleep(5)
        self.change_text.emit('I did something')
```

Comment: exactly on the point. I think I got it now - thank you very much